# замена картинки, путем наведении курсора на разные области этой картинки, где к каждой области привязана своя картинка

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть, например, картинка дома. Нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора на область крыши, появлялась другая картинка этого дома, но уже с другой крышей, а при наведении на дверь появлялась картинка дома с другой дверью. Также, помимо смены картинки, при наведении на эту область, нужно, чтобы появлялось модальное окно с описанием. Вопрос в том, как лучше сделать замену картинки, при наведении на определенную область?

Пришла идея как сделать на css: через `hover` - сделать пустой `div`, над нужной областью этой картинки. При наведении на эту область открывается скрытый (`display:block;`) `div` с нужной картинкой. Но это получается немного запутано, так как нужно сделать 6 разных областей на картинке.

Есть ли какой-то более простой способ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наведите на подушку-мяч на кровати. Пример использования метода jquery  `mouseover()`:

```js
$('#ball1').mouseover(function(){
 $(this).css('background-image','url("http://i.imgur.com/jItGQlA.png?1")');
});
```

```css
 #cont {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url('http://babypalace.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/futbolnaya_tema_v_detskoi_2.jpg');
  position: relative;
 }
 div > div {
  position: absolute;
 }
#ball1 {
    height: 42px;
    left: 228px;
    top: 229px;
    width: 42px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script><div id="cont">
 <div id="ball1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, решение хорошо подходит к мой ситуации. Хорошего дня!

Comment: Если ответ ответчика вас устроил, примите его, нажав галочку.